# How to only store (the remotly retrieved image) on ram and not save the file, in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Corona sdk offers a feature where you can [get a remote image](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/loadRemoteImage.html)

The syntax is :

> display.loadRemoteImage( url, method, listener [, params],
>   destFilename [, baseDir] [, x, y] )

My question is: how to load the remote image into the ram directly without having to store it on mobile? I don't want to store in `destFilename` how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to display an image without having it stored on the device.  All browsers work the same way. They locally store images till they aren't needed.

The best option for you would be to store it on a temporary directory, so that when the app is closed or the phone is shutdown or restarted, the file is lost and doesn't take up hard memory.

You can do this using the following as the baseDir:
`system.TemporaryDirectory`

Here is an example grabbed from Corona's documentation:

```
display.loadRemoteImage("http://coronalabs.com/images/coronalogogrey.png", "GET",networkListener, "coronalogogrey.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 50,50 )
```

**EDIT**

This is a quote from another answer that shows how applications are ran in general: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/80867/understanding-ram-sd-card-and-device-memory-of-an-smartphone

> RAM - Random Accessed Memory - When running an application on your
>   phone, the application is loaded from your device memory into the RAM,
>   just like on a computer, the main purpose for this is access speed is
>   far greater in RAM.

In your case, you are loading a remote image into the temporary folder at runtime. The /tmp folder is in your sandbox and that is on mobile storage. However, you are using it on the RAM currently on your running app.

When loaded, this image is placed temporarily into this folder on the RAM for quick and efficient use. Before closing your app, I assume you will be cleaning your temp folder. This image will never be stored in the temp folder for later use. It is solely used during run-time, which is using RAM.

I cannot be 100% certain of this because Corona does not have any documentation on this. All that I clearly know is 1) RAM is used for running apps 2) tmp folder is normally cleared before closing an app. These facts can be used to validate that the remote image being used during runtime is placed directly onto the RAM. For 100% assurance, we would need someone who studies mobile memory management.

Think of it a variable. Your variables are created at runtime and is placed on RAM for temporary use. You are doing the exact same thing here by loading a remote image at runtime. If the image were in your app folder then loading it would just load it from memory into RAM. In your case, you are most likely using RAM for your image storage.

Comment: this is what I'm doing, i use the TemporaryDirectory , I was searching for a way to store on ram directly, anyway thanks, I think there is no way to add to ram directly?

Comment: The temporary directory is on the RAM. RAM is temporary memory. If this is still not what you are looking for, then unfortunately, there is no other way to store images.

Comment: I thought that the temporary directory is on the mobile phone storage, could you provide me with a website that confirms that the temp folder is stored on ram for corona sdk? I searched a lot, if you could quote that from a website or reference then you answer will be accepted, and all problem is solved, thanks Brett.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: I was incorrect by saying the tmp directory is on the RAM, though. The temp directory you are adding the image to is on the RAM, most likely.